# Converting PostgreSQL interval to seconds produces wrong values

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I am working with some intervals in Postgresql and I am not sure I understand how intervals work.

What I am trying to do is convert an interval to seconds.
So I have the following values:

```
select extract ('epoch' from '1 year'::INTERVAL);
```

Produces the number 31557600. If we divide this number by (60*60*24) which is the number of seconds in a day, we get 365.
**So a year in a postgresql interval has 365 days**.

```
select extract ('epoch' from '1 month'::INTERVAL);
```

Produces the number 2592000. If we divide this number by (60*60*24) we get 30.
**So a month in postgresql interval has 30 days.**

So by that logic, I am trying to calculate the number of seconds in the following interval:

```
select extract ('epoch' from '2 year 2 month 1 day 10 hour 5 minute'::INTERVAL);
```

I am using the following formula to calculate the result from the above query:

```
SELECT (years * 365 * 24 * 3600) + (months * 30 * 24 * 3600) + (days * 24 * 3600) + (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60);
```

When we replace the variables with values, the expression looks like this:

```
SELECT (2 * 365 * 24 * 3600) + (2 * 30 * 24 * 3600) + (1 * 24 * 3600) + (10 * 3600) + (5 * 60);
```

The problem that I am having is that the result of the first query (`SELECT extract...`) produces the result **68421900** while the query from the formula above produces the result **68378700**.
From my understanding, the results should be identical, but there is 12 hours (43200 seconds) difference between the results. Why is this happening?

It is important to note that if I remove the years from the interval I am getting the same result from both queries, so I guess it has something to do with the years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is integer arithmetic. The mistake is here:

> ```
> select extract ('epoch' from '1 year'::INTERVAL);
> ```
>
> Produces the number 31557600. If we divide this number by (60*60*24) which is the number of seconds in a day, we get 365.

What you probably did was

```
SELECT 31557600 / (60 * 60 * 24);

 ?column? 
----------
      365
(1 row)
```

But the reality is:

```
SELECT extract (epoch FROM INTERVAL '1 year') / (60 * 60 * 24);

 ?column? 
----------
   365.25
(1 row)
```

So the length of a year in PostgreSQL is actually 365 days and 6 hours. This is an approximation (the true value is slightly less) and should account for leap years.

---

Note: These values are kind of arbitrary because there is no single correct answer for “how long is one (calendar) month” or “how long is one (calendar) year” — the answer depends on the individual month or year.

If you add an `interval` to a `timestamp with time zone`, the result will always be correct, because in that context the exact length is clear.

---

As to the question why a year is assumed to have 365.25 days, while a month has 30 days, here is what the source has to say in `src/include/datatype/timestamp.h`:

```c
/*
 * Assorted constants for datetime-related calculations
 */

#define DAYS_PER_YEAR   365.25  /* assumes leap year every four years */
#define MONTHS_PER_YEAR 12
/*
 *      DAYS_PER_MONTH is very imprecise.  The more accurate value is
 *      365.2425/12 = 30.436875, or '30 days 10:29:06'.  Right now we only
 *      return an integral number of days, but someday perhaps we should
 *      also return a 'time' value to be used as well.  ISO 8601 suggests
 *      30 days.
 */
#define DAYS_PER_MONTH  30              /* assumes exactly 30 days per month */
#define HOURS_PER_DAY   24              /* assume no daylight savings time changes */

/*
 *      This doesn't adjust for uneven daylight savings time intervals or leap
 *      seconds, and it crudely estimates leap years.  A more accurate value
 *      for days per years is 365.2422.
 */
#define SECS_PER_YEAR   (36525 * 864)   /* avoid floating-point computation */
#define SECS_PER_DAY    86400
#define SECS_PER_HOUR   3600
#define SECS_PER_MINUTE 60
#define MINS_PER_HOUR   60
```

So I guess the reason is that ISO 8601 decrees that a month has 30 days.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wouldn't have noticed that in a million years :)
Anyway, why is the time added only to the year? Wouldnt it be best if the length of months, hours, minutes or even seconds was adjusted so that 12 months would add up to 1 year and 6 hours?

Comment: That would have been one way to do it. I agree that the current behavior is somewhat inconsistent: if the length of a year is inspired by the [tropical year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_year), why not use the [lunar month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month) too? Or 365.25 / 12? I have read up in the source and will add the relevant parts to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem and eventually found something that worked.

```
SELECT AVG( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (end_ts - start_ts)) )
```

produced incorrect values.

```
SELECT AVG( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL (end_ts - start_ts)) )
```

produced a syntax error.

Extracting the epochs separately from the start and stop timestamps and then running the math on them worked.

```
SELECT AVG( ( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM end_ts) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM start_ts) ) )
```

I threw in some additional math to translate to hours.

```
SELECT AVG( ( EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM end_ts) - EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM start_ts) )::FLOAT/86400 )
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your statement `So a month in postgresql interval has 30 days.` is wrong:

```
janbet=> select '2019-01-01'::date + '1 month'::interval;
      ?column?
---------------------
 2019-02-01 00:00:00
(1 row)

janbet=> select '2019-02-01'::date + '1 month'::interval;
      ?column?
---------------------
 2019-03-01 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

As you see above, month could be 31 days or 28 days, depending on the context. It is, in fact, a **month** and months have different lengths.

The same applies to `'2 year 2 month 1 day 10 hour 5 minute'::interval`:

```
janbet=> select '2019-01-01'::date + '2 year 2 month 1 day 10 hour 5 minute'::interval - '2019-01-01'::date;
     ?column?
-------------------
 791 days 10:05:00
(1 row)

janbet=> select '2021-01-01'::date + '2 year 2 month 1 day 10 hour 5 minute'::interval - '2021-01-01'::date;
     ?column?
-------------------
 790 days 10:05:00
(1 row)
```

We get a different result depending on whether those `2 years` include leap year or not.

My best guess about your 12 hours is that 2 years include leap year in 50% of cases so this is `one day * 1/2`. In fact, if you repeat your calculation with '3 years', you get a 18-hour difference, so I'm prette sure it works that way.

I understand that could be surprising, but I can't think of other result that would be consistent with variable lengths of years/months and this is the desired `interval` 
behaviour.

Comment: But if that is the case, why does `select extract ('epoch' from '1 month'::INTERVAL);` return seconds that are equal to 30 days? Why does it not return 28 or 29 or 31? I understand and see the logic in your examples when you add it to a date, but that means that when it is used without date, the result is unpredictable?

Comment: Why 30 and not something else (`365 / 12` maybe?) - I have no idea. No consistent arithmetic is **possible** so probably someone decided that `1 month is 30 days` is the best possible answer most of the times and that's all. Result is not **unpredictable**, but I don't know the exact rules. They could be pretty complicated to yield this *best answer* as many times as possible.

Comment: Well yes, but I need those rules in order to use the `interval` type consistently. I am thankful for your answer which is definitely in the right direction but it is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: IMHO `interval` is just not meant to be used the way you want to use it. For example,  quoting https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL#6._Many_larger_INTERVAL_values.2C_like_the_calendar_values_they_reflect.2C_are_not_constant_in_length_when_expressed_in_smaller_INTERVAL_values `Many larger INTERVAL values, like the calendar values they reflect, are not constant in length when expressed in smaller INTERVAL values` - and what you're looking for is exact length in this smaller INTERVALs (seconds).
Anyway, I'm also intrested in other answers.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and in the end, it might be the best answer that I am going to get :)

Comment: Just an idea: you might consider a constant point of reference (eg. the epoch start, 1970-01-01), and compute seconds the way i described before, by adding interval to the date and subtracting the date. Not a beautiful solution, but at least you'll have a consistent and predictable `interval`-based arithmetic.